# How to clear heap memory in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, dart, web, heap-memory, flutter-web

Im working on flutter web.I need to know how to clear heap memory in flutter web.
I have used simple text widget but it takes 144mb as heap.
I dont know where from it comes.
My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Demo',
    home: Text('hi'),
  ));
}
```

I have attached pictures for reference[image]

[image]

kindly tell me how to clear this memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're asking is how to run flutter on web such that it consumes less memory at the outset, the answer may be to run it in release mode using the html renderer rather than the canvas renderer. (More on renderers: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/web-renderers)

`flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html --release`

This worked for me. Running a simple hello world app, my heap was measuring ~150mb even in release mode. Then, I switched to html renderer. Now, in debug mode the heap is ~60mb. In release mode it's ~7mb.

Comment: Though this works, canvas shouldn't be taking this much memory. I added an issue to the flutter github: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/81790. My guess is it likely has something to do with our environment setup, otherwise there would already be an issue for this.

Comment: It isn't the environment setup. It's a known issue with flutter web that's being worked on.

Comment: Could you point me towards a source?

Answer (score 0):

Two points here:

1. My assumption is that you are running application in debug mode. In debug mode application includes a lot of things for debugging purposes that will not be included in your release app. For instance, application that I am working on on start with log in screen takes ~100Mb in debug mode, while it takes only ~20Mb in release mode. So try to compile your app in release mode and see.
2. I do not think you can clear memory. Dart has GC (garbage collector) that does it for you. All you need to do as developer is to make sure you do not have objects that can not be garbage collected and thus remain in heap of VM causing memory leak over time.

Comment: I am running in profile mode. I have disposed the variables properly.But couldnt find the root cause of this 144mb heap memory.

Comment: Something is wrong with your setup. I am just running same "hi" app  you provided and I am taking 7.7MB snapshot. What's your Flutter version ?

Comment: @AlexRadzishevsky, I am having basically the same issue as Sarath, approximately 150mb of memory for a simple hello world app. Running in release mode. Flutter version 2.0.5